# ReportViewer Division by zero

Tags: reportviewer

I have some formulas in my reports, and to prevent divsion by zero I do like this in the expression field:

=IIF(Fields!F1.Value <> 0, Fields!F2.Value/Fields!F1.Value, 0)

This normally works fine, but when both F1 and F2 are zero, I get "#Error" in the report, and I get this warning: "The Value expression for the textbox ‘textbox196’ contains an error: Attempted to divide by zero."

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be a prettier way than this, but this should work:

```
=IIF(Fields!F1.Value <> 0, Fields!F2.Value / 
   IIF(Fields!F1.Value <> 0, Fields!F1.Value, 42), 0)
```

Comment: Disgusting, but works..

Why can't I simply write:
IF Fields!F1.Value <>0 Then
 Fields!F2.Value / Fields!F1.Value
Else
 0 
End If
like CrystalReports.. which I'm migrating away from.. sigh.

Answer (score 3):

IIF() is just a function, and like with any function *all* the arguments  are evaluated *before* the function is called, including `Fields!F2.Value/Fields!F1.Value`.  In other words, it will attempt to divide by zero in spite of the `Fields!F1.Value <> 0` condition.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, starting to remember VB.. 

But, what kind of solutions exits to this problem?
As far as I know, I cannot enter an VBA snippet as an expression, or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure:  VB9 (.Net 3.5) supports a new If() _operator_ that works like a C-based ternary operator (?).  VB8 (.Net2.0) supports inline If/Else constructs.  But I don't think either will work with ReportViewer.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think this explains the problem. neslekkiM's thing works fine when only F1 == 0, but not when *both* are 0, right? Plus Joel, your division expression doesn't match what neslekkiM wrote - his has F1 as the divisor, not F2.

Comment: And what's more...
If you add an column to an dataset, uses an expression with IIF(F1<>0,F2/F1,0) THEN the damn thing WORKS??
Why is IIF implemented so differently all over the place?
Exce, VB, ReportingServices, ADO, etc.. sigh..

Comment: =IIf(Fields!F1.Value = 0, "N/A", Fields!F2.Value / IIf(Fields!F2.Value = 0, 1, Fields!F2.Value))

Answer (score 0):

However, you can use

```
if Fields!F1.Value <> 0 
then 
Fields!F2.Value/Fields!F1.Value
else 0
```

which should work, since it doesn't evaluate the then clause if the "if" section is false.

Comment: do see the comment I did on the accepted answer, maybe this have changed now, but I could not write it as this back then.