# ReportViewer question

Tags: reportviewer

I have a column that divides a field by another field. And if it is 0 I it prints Error. How can I get it to print nothing or a 0 in this situation?

Comment: You really should provide a little more details (platform, language, application). And what do you mean with "divides a field by another field"?

Comment: winform, vb.net. 
Basically I would like to hide/show a cell/column based on a value.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just create an expression for the result column and display the result conditionally?

Eg, instead of:

`=ColumnA!Value/ColumnB!Value`

Use something like:

`=Iff(ColumnB!Value <> 0, ColumnA!Value/ColumnB!Value, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one:

```
=IIF(Fields!F1.Value <> 0, Fields!F2.Value / 
   IIF(Fields!F1.Value <> 0, Fields!F1.Value, 42), 0)
```

Also check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158508/reportviewer-division-by-zero) for more information.