# Comparison in reportviewer doesn't work

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

How does comparison in reports work? I've tried the next expression:

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!COEF.Value), 0, Fields!SUM.Value - Fields!SUM.Value / Fields!COEF.Value)
```

It never was 0. Then I've changed my sql query to make COEF = 0 when COEF is null.

```
=Iif(Fields!COEF.Value = 0, 0, Fields!SUM.Value - Fields!SUM.Value / Fields!COEF.Value)
```

But it always сalculates by the expression.

Comment: And is there a row in result set where the COEF is zero ?

Comment: Sure. But I get #error there. It seem like it tries to devide by zero...

Comment: If I change divider by constant it works properly

Comment: it's similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158508/reportviewer-division-by-zero

Answer (score 0):

Problem is both True/False part of `IIf` is evaluated before you get results. But you can write your own simple function to get over this restriction.

E.g. - in your Report->Report properties->Code

```
Public Function SafeDiv(n as decimal, d as decimal) as decimal
  If d = 0
    SafeDiv = 0
  Else
    SafeDiv= n / d
  End If
End Function
```

And then in your property

```
=Fields!SUM.Value - Code.SafeDiv(Fields!SUM.Value, Fields!COEF.Value)
```

Comment: I used one more IIF.`=IIF(Fields!COEF.Value <> 0, Fields!SUM.Value - Fields!SUM.Value / IIF(Fields!COEF.Value = 0, 1, Fields!COEF.Value), Nothing)`